# How can I build rest API with nodejs and limit user access with whitelisted ip or domain?

Tags: node.js

How can I build rest API with nodejs and limit user access with whitelisted ip or domain?

so, if domain or ip address not whitelisted, they cant access the API. 
anything I need to build that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to whitelist domains that can make cross-origin requests to your API.

You can use something like [NPM's CORS package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors), which will let you develop a request whitelist and reject calls from unapproved origins.